# Call overloaded function from each object in std::vector

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, c++17

I'm working on my own menu system in OpenGL.
What I want is to have all my objects that are related to the menu in one vector, so I could easily just loop them all like this:

```
for (auto i : menuObjects)
{
    i.checkInputs();
    i.draw();
}
```

I've tried with other looping methods, even having `this->draw();` inside the base class' function, but that obviously ended up in an infinite loop.

My base class is basically this:

```
class menuObject
{
public:

    virtual void draw() { }
    virtual void checkInputs() { }

};
```

And inherited classes are like this:

```
class Button : public menuObject
{
public: 
    void draw()
    {
        ... drawing here ...
    }

    void checkInputs()
    {
        ... checking inputs here ...
    }

};
```

And here's how I save them in my vector:

```
std::vector<menuObject> menuObjects = {
    Button(... parameters here ...)
};
```

It never goes to the overloaded function.
I would rather not have every different menu object in their own vector.
Any ideas? <3

Comment: Where have you overloaded any function? Do you mean overridden functions?

Comment: They overloaded the draw and checkInputs methods

Comment: @GabrielAlexander Doesn't look like it. Op hashave overridden those functions though, which is why SolidMercury suspects that's what they may have meant instead.

Comment: oh yeah, i got the terms confused myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: You have encountered object slicing. Your vector needs to store pointers (preferably smart pointers) and your for loop needs to use `auto&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're having is that you cannot store objects of different types directly within a vector.

```
std::vector<menuObject> menuObjects = {
Button(... parameters here ...)
};
```

The above code slices the Button into a menuObject. Object slicing occurs when a derived class is value-assigned to the base class. Any information associated with the derived class is lost.

What you want to do is to use pointers to allow for polymorphism.

So your `std::vector<menuObjects>` would become either `std::vector<menuObjects*>` or `vector<std::unique_ptr<menuObjects>`. Use the latter if this vector is going to be responsible for managing the lifetime of menuObjects and the former if not.

Side note: if you do use the former option (i.e. raw pointers), make sure the remove invalidated pointers from the vector when the lifetime of a menuObject ends before the vector's lifetime ends.